# I am create a simple route using node express and passport-jwt to authenticate with json web token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, passport-jwt

I got token for email and password using json web token, but when i type this http://localhost:3001/users/profile url as a post request and pass token as Authorizaton header in postman tool ,I got always unautherized.

my app.js file is,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const mongoose =require("mongoose")
const config =require("./config/database")

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())


const users =require("./routes/users")

const passport =require("passport")
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



require("./config/passport-jwt")(passport)





const port = 3001

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")))

app.use("/users",users)


 mongoose.connect(config.url).then(()=>{
    console.log("database is connected")
},err=>{
    console.log("database is not connected",err)
})



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listing to port : ${port}`)
})
```

My passport-jwt.js file is,

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const config =require("./database")
const User =require("../models/user")

const opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;


module.exports=function(passport) {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function (jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findUserById({_id: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
                // or you could create a new account
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

my routes.js file is,

```
const express = require('express')
const router =express.Router()
const User =require("../models/user")
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config =require("../config/database")
const passport =require("passport")



router.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
    const email =req.body.email
    const password =req.body.password

    User.checkEmail(email,(err,user)=>{
      if(err) throw err
      if(!user){
       res.status(404).json({msg:"user not found"})
      }
      User.checkPassword(password,user.password,(err,match)=>{
          if(err) throw err

          if(match){
              const token = jwt.sign({user},config.secret,{expiresIn:1233333});
              res.status(200).json({
               token:"JWT"+token,
               user:{
                   id:user._id,
                   name:user.name,
                   email:user.email,
                   password:user.password,

               }
              })
          }
      })



})


})


router.post('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt',{ session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.json({user:req.user})
    }
);
```

my model.js file is,

```
const mongoose =require("mongoose")


const schema =mongoose.Schema

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


const userSchema =new schema({
    username:{type:String,required:true},
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},

})


const User = module.exports =mongoose.model("User",userSchema)



 module.exports.saveData =function (userData,callback) {

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(userData.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
           userData.password=hash

           if(err) throw err
           userData.save(callback)
        });
    });
}

module.exports.checkEmail=function (email,callback) {
      const query ={email:email}
      User.findOne(query,callback)
}

module.exports.checkPassword=function (plainPassword,hash,callback) {

    bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
       if (err) throw err
       if(res){
           callback(null,res)
       }
    });
}


module.exports.findUserById =function (id,callback) {
 User.findOne(id,callback)
}
```

my database.js file is,

```
module.exports ={
    "url":"mongodb://localhost:27017/authapp",
    "secret" :"secretkey"
}
```

**please help me to fix this,